# Color substring in table cell based on html tags

Tags: html, string, javafx, colors, cell

Since JavaFX libraries does not have the method HTML.fromHtml as android does, I try to find a solution for that.

I've got a TableView with a TableColumn which shows a simple html tagged string. The substring between the tags should be painted in a specific color. How can I achieve that?

```
colConstruction.setCellFactory(param -> new TableCell<GrammarData, String>() {
        @Override
        public void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(item, empty);
            String sampleString = "<c1>A<ce> is a charackter, <c2>B<ce> too."
            this.setText(sampleString);
        }
    });
```

E.g. A shall be red, B shall be blue. (I replaced the html tags)

Similar questions were only about coloring the whole cell text, but not parts of it.

I also tried:

```
Text text = new Text(sampleString);
text.setFill(Color.RED);
this.setText(text.toString());
```

Although it would have been worked, I then couldn't use different colors.

**Edit:**
The Tags `<c1>`, `<c2>`, `<c... >` are going to be replaced by `<font color='#FFFFFF'>`, depending on the given number. `<ce>` is going to be replaced by `</font>`. Since I use the same data for android and I need to have dynamically choosen colors, I use those patterns.

**Solution:**
Using a `WebView` element inside of the cell fixed this issue.

```
colConstruction.setCellFactory(param -> new TableCell<GrammarData, String>() {
        @Override
        public void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(item, empty);
            if (item != null) {
                WebView view = new WebView();
                view.setPrefSize(650, 80);
                WebEngine engine = view.getEngine();
                setGraphic(view);
                engine.loadContent(item.replace("<c1>", "<font color='#F9193E'>")
                        .replace("<c2>", "<font color='#0AD2F5'>")
                        .replace("<c3>", "<font color='#96F023'>")
                        .replace("<ce>", "</font>"));
            }
        }
});
```

You just have to care about the size of the `WebView`.

Comment: If you use actual HTML tags, you could simply use a `WebView` in the cell to display the HTML. If you want to parse it out (and I don't understand what your tags are supposed to be doing in the code you posted), you can add `Text`s to a `TextFlow` and color them each differently.

Comment: OK, so if you actually make those replacements, you can simply display the resulting HTML in a `WebView`. Have you tried that? (And why did you undo the edits I made?)

Comment: Didn't try it yet, since it has seemed to be more like a work around than a proper solution. Using a text flow is a good idea. I will try both. I thought their might be a smaller solution I have missed. Thank you for your fast answer!

Comment: How is it a workaround? `WebView` is exactly the correct tool for displaying HTML, and that is exactly what you say you are trying to do.

Comment: Did you try using https://jsoup.org/  ?

Comment: @James_D I thought that a `WebView` is used to display web pages written in HTML and is therefore an inefficient option. It might slow down the population, since it's such a powerful and big object. @Xlint Xms could you give an example how java parses colors with jsoup? I've never used it.

Comment: Did you try it? You sound like you are trying to solve performance problems that might not exist.

Comment: @James_D I tried it and it works. I just wasn't sure if that is a proper solution, since putting another element inside of the cell. However, I still don't know how to identify the most efficient solutions. Thanks for your effort!